# How can I make an output stream that encloses unspecified types within brackets in C++?

Tags: c++, ostream

First timer on StackOverflow, please don't eat me alive.

Here is my problem: I use classes that define the operator << to output their member values. Unfortunately, these classes forgot that member values can be other classes and they do not enclose themselves between (let's say) curly brackets to keep the structural information intact. **I cannot modify these classes, nor have I information on their structure.** This means I can't just brutally browse myself their contents.

For the sake of the example, below is a chunk of code that has two classes, A and B (where B contains a class A) which output their member variables (`"<variable_name>=<value>, "`). Here is the result of using the << operator on cout for b:

```
cout << b; // yields: m_a=m_foo=43586, m_bar=43604, m_foo=47938
```

One can see that it is impossible to tell whether A has one or two member variables (does m_bar belong to A or B?).

I have spent some time looking into a wrapper around ostream that would add curly brackets around things that are neither C-style strings nor ints. Unfortunately, the recursion is far from as trivial as I initially thought.

```
produced result: B= { m_a=m_foo=43586, m_bar=43604, m_foo=47938 } 
expected result: B= { m_a= { m_foo=43586, m_bar=43604 } , m_foo=47938 }
```

(but it works great for `wrapper << 42 << "cstring" << variable_with_other_type;`)

And here are my questions: *Am I doing this completely wrong? Did I miss something obvious? Is the solution to my problem significantly more complicated than my approach?*

This is the full code (<strike>it requires C++11 rvalues, but I am stuck with an outdated version of gcc that has only `-std=c++0x`, so it needs to be as little C++11 as possible</strike> (changed the rvalue to a const value to get rid of C++11)).

```
#include <sstream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

/* THIS BELOW CANNOT BE MODIFIED */

class A
{
    public:
        A(){
            m_foo=0xAA42;
            m_bar=0xAA54;
        };
        virtual ~A(){};
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a);
        int m_foo;
        int m_bar;
};

class B
{
    public:
        B(A a) {
            m_foo = 0xBB42;
            m_a = a;
        }
        virtual ~B(){};
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const B& b);
        A m_a;
        int m_foo;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a)
{
    // os << "{"; // woops forgot to uncomment this
    os << "m_foo=" << a.m_foo;
    os << ", ";
    os << "m_bar=" << a.m_bar;
    // os << "}"; // woops forgot to uncomment this
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const B& b)
{
    // os << "{"; // woops forgot to uncomment this
    os << "m_a=" << b.m_a;
    os << ", ";
    os << "m_foo=" << b.m_foo;
    // os << "}"; // woops forgot to uncomment this
    return os;
}

/* THIS BELOW CAN BE MODIFIED */

class WrappingOstream
{
    public:
        WrappingOstream(ostream& stream);
        virtual ~WrappingOstream();

        template <class T> WrappingOstream& operator<<(const T& x) {
            m_stream << " { " << x << " } ";
            //*this << " { " << x << " } "; //segfaults when replacing m_stream with *this
            return *this;
        }

        WrappingOstream& operator<<(int i)
        {
            m_stream << i;
            return *this;
        }

        WrappingOstream& operator<<(const char* cstr)
        {
            m_stream << cstr;
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        ostream& m_stream;
};

WrappingOstream::WrappingOstream(ostream& stream) :
    m_stream(stream)
{
    //ctor
}

WrappingOstream::~WrappingOstream()
{
    //dtor
}



int main() {

    A a;
    B b(a);

    ostringstream ss;
    WrappingOstream wos(ss);
    wos << b << endl;
    cout << "produced result: B=" << ss.str();
   cout << "expected result: B=" << " { m_a= { m_foo=43586, m_bar=43604 } , m_foo=47938 }";

}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you only need to wrap A or are you looking for a general solution that will work for any custom class?

Comment: I've read your question, and although I cannot help you much, I would advise you to go through this page: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization. Perhaps you will find something helpful there.

Comment: @NathanOliver I need the general solution. It is probable that I can get it to work much more easily with wrapping only A, but at this point, I would like the generic answer for science.

Comment: @piotrsmaron Thanks. I've thought about serialization, as this is close to what I want, but the classes I use are much more complex and only print a (relevant) subset of their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here is what it boils down to:

*What I'm trying to do specifically is apparently not possible to achieve.* Why that is so is not without interest, so, here's why. Back to my problem.

What I actually need to do to achieve what I want is *not* wrap around ostream, because that means that I can't hijack the in-depth printing of the class `A` within `B`'s output (remember, I can't modify those classes). Indeed, B uses directly an ostream for that. I took me some time to realize that modifying ostream's behaviour was the only way, as trivial as it may now appear to me.

So what I need to do is *derive from* ostream and modify its behaviour (specifically the behaviour of its method `operator<<`). Which is, as it turns out, not possible because there's no polymorphism with `ostream::operator<<` as is not virtual. At least, I don't think it can be achieved easily (let alone trivially).

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this piece of code:

```
template <class T> WrappingOstream& operator<<(const T& x) {
            m_stream << " { " << x << " } ";
```

When you are passing B in `main`, you are working with WrappingOstream, but inside the `operator<<` you are working with `m_stream`, which is a plain `std::ostream`. Therefore when you are printing A, it calls the generic `operator<<` and not the one from `WrappingOstream`. Try adding debug printouts to those methods to see what gets called when.

You could be able to overcome the problem by subclassing the `std::ostringstream` directly with `WrappingOstream`.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed (one of the) the problem(s). But the more I think about this, the more I feel like there will be a chicken and egg problem.

(editing this comment at the moment, am not used to the enter key sending my message, duh)

Comment: Aaaaaand comments cannot be edited after more than 5 minutes. The more you learn. So there is the full comment:

Yes, that is indeed (one of the) the problem(s). But the more I think about this, the more I feel like there will be a chicken and egg problem.

**If** I subclass `std::ostringstream`, and somehow catch my class A. Then what? I can't pass it to a normal ostream, that defeats the purpose of the whole thing. I can't pass it to my wrapper, because we'll need to go deeper every time we reach A (infinite recursion ahoy).
However, right now, I have had an idea which I want to investigate.